# Usar classe Auth em arquivo de configuração no Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, auth

Estou usando o [barryvdh/laravel-elfinder](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-elfinder). Este gera o arquivo de configuração `/config/elfinder.php.` Dentro deste arquivo, informo o caminho para upload de arquivos do ElFinder.

Preciso que cada usuário tenha a sua pasta de uploads. Pensei em criar uma variável `$dir` de acordo com o id do usuário logado mas não consigo usar a classe `Auth` dentro do arquivo `/config/elfinder.php`.

Tem jeito de pegar o usuário logado de outra forma?

O arquivo está assim:

```
<?php

$dir = 'arquivos';    
return array('dir' => [$dir] );
```

Quero algo assim:

```
<php

$dir = 'arquivos/'.Auth::id();
return array('dir' => [$dir] );
```

Já tentei assim:

```
<?php

use Auth;
$id=Auth::id();

$dir = 'arquivos/'.$id;    
return array('dir' => [$dir] );
```

E retorna este erro:

> ```
> Warning: The use statement with non-compound name 'Auth' has no effect in /var/www/html/dna/config/elfinder.php on line 3
>
> Fatal error: Class 'Auth' not found in /var/www/html/dna/config/elfinder.php on line 5
> ```

Comment: Não consegue colocar no topo da página `use Auth;`

Comment: Não funciona, já tentei

Comment: Vai dar pau mesmo. Essa classe provavelmente nem passou para o processamento de alias que o Laravel faz internamente. Provalvemente, é a ordem que o script tá sendo executado internamente.

Comment: Veja se funciona sessão. Ao logar coloca o ID na sessão e pega no arquivo do elfinder.php.

Comment: @Gumball não vai funcionar também. Tem um problema muito mais sério do que isso no Laravel 5. Os middlewares e o autoload afetam o carregamento dos dados do Auth também.

Comment: Se tratando dos arquivos da pasta `config` é verdade. É preciso ter uma outra saída.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esse erro costuma acontecer porque o arquivo de configuração é carregado antes de acontecer o processamento interno que o Laravel faz para a classe `Auth` (que é um alias).

Além desse problema, dependendo dos locais da aplicação onde você pode querer tentar acessar o valor de `Auth::user`, o retorno pode vir `null` independente de estar logado ou não. Isso ocorre porque os dados do `Auth` só são acessíveis depois do carregamento desses middlewares abaixo:

```
    \Tmt\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
```

Eles são responsáveis pela sessão, cookies e afins.

## Solução

Você pode considerar a utilização da função `config` para poder definir de acordo com o usuário logado dentro de um Middleware. Pois usando um middleware, está trabalhando com dados vindos da sessão, já que os mesmos já foram carregados pelos middlewares anteriores.

Por exemplo

```
class Authenticate
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        // Restante do código

        config(['elfinder.dir' => ['arquivos/' . auth()->user()->id]])

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

É bom observar que a ideia de usar o `config` é para trabalhar com dados imutáveis.

Talvez ainda fosse interessante observar se a biblioteca que você está usando não existe um método para você poder definir qual diretório vai trabalhar.

Comment: Exatamente. É preciso reescrever a variável no ato do login por meio de uma Middleware.Tipo: `Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth', 'middleware' => ['auth', 'path-upload']], function(){  });`. Daí na Middleware `path-upload` reescreve.

Comment: @Gumball isso, se ela precisar ela pode definir um `middleware` global, ou então botar ele dentro do grupo `web`.